# Make wider input

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.2.0 and I have the following code:

```
<form name="singUpForm" id="singUpForm">

    <div class="top-margin">

        <div class="input-append">
            <label>Contact<span class="text-danger"></span></label>
            <input type="url" class="span2" ng-model="Person.url" required="required">
            <button class="btn" type="button">
                Test
            </button>
            <button class="btn" type="button">
                Ayuda
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="alert alert-warning" ng-hide='singUpForm.email.$valid' >
            Ingrese una url válida.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 text-right">
            <button ng-disabled='singUpForm.$invalid' type="submit" class="btn btn-action" ng-click="signUp()">
                Guardar datos
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to make the input type="url" wider traying to force it to get the 100% of the space inside the form with the two buttons on the right on the same line.

I need something like that:
[image]

Comment: So you want the input to be 100% of the width and the label above it with the buttons below?

Comment: Have you tried using CSS? `.input-append input { width: 100%; display: block; }`

Comment: yes!, after the code you see, I had a input but without the buttons, I was using the form-control class and it was perfect, now I need to change and add the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'form-control'` , `'row'` and `'col'`

In `'xs'` screen you can change the class as `'col-xs-6'` in both columns

## [UPDATED DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/qMiOYr7OaU)

```
 <div class="input-append">
            <label>Contact<span class="text-danger"></span></label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-lg-10">
                <input type="url" class="form-control" ng-model="Person.url" required="required" />
                    </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-2">
                    <button class="btn" type="button">
                        Test
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn" type="button">
                        Ayuda
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I know that but I need the text field and the buttons on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the input attribute to a specific size `<input size="100">`.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply:

```
style="width:100%"
```

in the `<input>` field, so it's like:

```
<input type="url" class="span2" ng-model="Person.url" required="required" style="width:100%">
```

Or you can add it in the CSS:

```
.span2{
width: 100%
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sc212f7s/